# How can I mount the actual content of ag-grid in enzyme?

Tags: javascript, enzyme, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

When using Ag-Grid, it would be nice to be able to target DOM elements for click testing (e.g., when setting up a click handler, would like to target the 2nd row, simulate a click, and spy on the resulting actions).

However, AG-Grid will not render the actual grid content in an Enzyme test, even when mounting. It will only render an empty div.

I've created a simple CodePen here (https://codesandbox.io/s/ag-grid-enzyme-9wkgn) that has a passing test and a failing test - however, I can't seem to get it to recognize the underlying grid content.

```
describe("ag-grid", () => {
  let app;
  beforeEach(() => {
    app = mount(<Grid />);
  });
  it("renders a grid", () => {
    expect(app.find("AgGridReact").length).toBe(1);
  });
  it("renders 3 rows", () => {
    console.log(app.debug());
    expect(app.find(".ag-row").length).toBe(3);
  });
});
```

I expect 2 successful tests - instead, the debug prints:

```
<Grid>
  <div className="ag-theme-balham" style={{...}}>
    <AgGridReact columnDefs={{...}} rowData={{...}}>
      <div style={{...}} />
    </AgGridReact>
  </div>
</Grid>
```

and the test results:

```
expect(received).toBe(expected)

Expected value to be (using ===):
  3
Received:
  0

  17 |   });
  18 |   it("renders 3 rows", () => {
  19 |     console.log(app.debug());
> 20 |     expect(app.find(".ag-row").length).toBe(3);
  21 |   });
  22 | });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can force a render to get the internals, i.e.

```
const agGridReactWrapper = component.find(AgGridReact);

expect(
  agGridReactWrapper.render()
  .find('div.ag-center-cols-viewport')
  .find('div.ag-row')
).toHaveLength(5);
```

This is after ensuring the grid has been set, see https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-testing-react/.

Unfortunately, this doesn't leave any means to simulate events on the DOM :(